# MSBuild: how to create a global property?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-propertygroup

When running MSBuild, anything passed in on the command line using `/p:MyProp=value` is accessible from every MSBuild script invoked (via the `MSBuild` task) from the main script. How can I define a property that is similarly accessible from every script, in a task?

For example:

```
Script1.proj:
[...]
<Target Name="Test">
  <MSBuild Projects="Script2.proj"/>
  <Message Text="Script1, GlobalProp1=$(GlobalProp1)"/>
  <Message Text="Script1, GlobalProp2=$(GlobalProp2)"/>
</Target>

Script2.proj:
[...]
<Target Name="Test">
  <!-- ??? Set GlobalProp2 = VALUE2 ??? -->
  <Message Text="Script2, GlobalProp1=$(GlobalProp1)"/>
  <Message Text="Script2, GlobalProp2=$(GlobalProp2)"/>
</Target>
```

If run like this: `msbuild Script1.proj /p:GlobalProp1=VALUE1` the above scripts produce the following output:

```
Script2, GlobalProp1=VALUE1
Script2, GlobalProp2=
Script1, GlobalProp1=VALUE1
Script1, GlobalProp2=
```

I'd like **Script2.proj** to set GlobalProp2 somehow to produce the following output:

```
Script2, GlobalProp1=VALUE1
Script2, GlobalProp2=VALUE2
Script1, GlobalProp1=VALUE1
Script1, GlobalProp2=VALUE2
```

Is this possible, and if so, how?

I've seen suggestions to use environment variables, but it seems that the *only* situation in which that helps is when the variable is set in the *parent* script, and the *child* script is invoked using the Exec task (otherwise the env.variable change has no effect).

Comment: btw environment variables also take effect when invoking VCBuild task, not just Exec task

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are using the [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx) task you have to pass the desired properties into the call using the Properties attribute so you should change you example to.

```
<Target Name="Test">  
    <MSBuild Projects="Script2.proj" 
        Properties="GlobalProp1=$(GlobalProp1);GlobalProp2=$(GlobalProp2)"
    />  
    <Message Text="Script1, GlobalProp1=$(GlobalProp1)"/>  
    <Message Text="Script1, GlobalProp2=$(GlobalProp2)"/>
</Target>
```

The properties must be explicitly passed, this is by design.

If you want a tighter integration then instead of using the MSBuild task you should just import the file(s) which will create 1 logical script.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work the other way around - I want to pass a change made in `Script2` back into `Script1`.

Comment: Instead of using the script using the MSBuild task then you should modify your process to just import the file. This provides a much tigheter integration.

Comment: Perfect - importing the script is the only way that actually worked so far. I'll mark this as accepted if you mention this in your answer.

Comment: If only you knew how much this answered helped! Thanks alot :-)

Answer (score 5):

You may use rsp file to define global properties. These properties are visible to child projects.

Comment: I can't see how my "sub-script" (`Script2.proj`) will be able to change them. Is it possible to do what I describe in the question using .rsp files?